# Setting required package version number in bdist_rpm setup.cfg

Tags: python, rpm

I am using Python's bdist_rpm to turn my Python code into rpm packages to be downloaded using yum.

My `setup.cfg` looks like this:

```
[bdist_rpm]
requires=python-flask,python-gevent,python-sqlalchemy
```

Whenever I try to set the version numbers, e.g. `python-flask-0.10.1`, `python-flask=0.10.1`, yum whinges that the packages need to be installed but doesn't install them itself, which makes me think I'm not correctly specifying the required packages.

So in a bdist_rpm setup.cfg, how do I set the version number of the package I require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to write something like that:

```
[bdist_rpm]
requires = python-flask = 0.10.1
    python-gevent
    python-sqlalchemy
```

After, you can verify if the specfile is correct:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --spec-only
```

You should have a line like:

```
Requires: python-flask = 0.10.1 python-gevent python-sqlalchemy
```

The trick here is that the space matter.